# Getting Database names from SQLAzure using powershell in azure devops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have a need to list down all the database names of a particular server on Azure.

```
$databases = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ServerName servername -ResourceGroupName resourcegroupname
foreach($dbs in $databases)
{
    $dbs.DatabaseName
}
```

this script works well run from local.

My question is how to run this from an Azure DevOps release using the powershell task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the Azure-Powershell task.

That way the pipeline can connect to the Proper Azure Subscirption, just like you connected to the Subscription manually from Powershell

Details about the Azure Powershell Task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops

[image]

[image]

But them I wonder what you want to do with the List of the databases.
Going out on a limb here, but you'd probably want the output back in the Pipeline. In which case please check out

- https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/preview/outputvariable.md
- Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=var01;isOutput=true]123"

Comment: Hello Tudor. I tried the Azure Powershell task, assigned the subscription's service connection, but it gave me the "The term 'Get-AzSqlDatabase' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function..." error. I set it to version 3 because version 5 gives me "Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' with Version: ''. "

Comment: what kind of Agent are you using ? are you hosting your own agent ?

Comment: if you are hosting your own agent you need to have the Az Powershell Module installed on the agent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-5.2.0

Comment: Yes using my own. Installing Az results in this Az module not installed. Having both the AzureRM and Az modules installed at the same time is not supported""

Comment: you can either:
- uninstall AzureRM and only install Az
- install-module Az -allowClobber and then Enable AzureRm Alaises: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/enable-azurermalias?view=azps-5.2.0

Ideally you would only want to have AZ module.
I have both AzureRM and AZ working side by side with the ARM Aliases enabled. However, it is risky and when MS does an breaking change on AZ (like the recent KV Secret fetching one) then you're in trouble

Comment: ah that would require rewrites on other scripts running on the same build server. Is there an AzureRM way of getting database names?

Comment: Yes, Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/get-azurermsqldatabase?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Comment: Most AzureRm commands were migrated. [Whatever]-AzureRm[Something] was added as [Whatever].Az[Something] initially in the AZ module

Comment: I went the RM way.
Also, on your original comment with 
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=var01;isOutput=true]123"
var01 is a pipeline variable, yes? and then I access it as $(var01) on the next powershell task?

Comment: Yes. But check out the documentation 1st, therea are a few caveats with the isOutput flag